# delay inside for loop, make toast every 2 seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So hi everyone, this is my first post in stackoverflow,
and i get stucked in 1 problem,

the problem is:
how can I add a delay inside for loop

I did lots of research and none of it works
So I decided to ask myself.

Here is my code

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();

for (langId = 1; langId <= 3; langId++) {
                handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (langId == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            delayTime += 2000;
                        }
                        if (langId == 2) {
                            Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            delayTime += 2000;
                        }
                        if (langId == 3) {
                            Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            delayTime += 2000;
                        }
                    }
                }, delayTime);
            }
```

So the result I want is:

```
"1" -> 2000ms -> "2" -> 2000ms -> "3"
```

Any ideas?

I tried `Thread.sleep(2000)`, it works, but it freeze the app, I need to do extra things during the process.

## Edit

Problem solved, this is the working code, also my final goal

```
        playBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Handler handler1 = new Handler();

            langId = 1;
            max = 1;
            delayTime = 0;
            selectedMP = 1;
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.noneDepart)).isChecked()) max = 3;
            else max = 6;

            handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.noneDepart)).isChecked()) {
                        String destdir = "KCR/Depart/" + Utils.getDestID(selectedDest) + "_";
                        if (viaRAC.isChecked()) destdir = destdir + "via_rac_";
                        destdir = destdir + langId + ".mp3";
                        if (selectedMP == 1) {
                            try {
                                afd = getAssets().openFd(destdir);
                                mp1.reset();
                                mp1.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                mp1.prepare();
                                mp1.start();
                                //Utils.RunOnUiThread(KCRdestActivity.this, mp1, sb1);
                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Play1)).setText("❙❙");
                                selectedMP = 2;
                                delayTime = mp1.getDuration() - 130;
                                Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, delayTime + "##" + destdir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            try {
                                afd = getAssets().openFd(destdir);
                                mp2.reset();
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                                //Utils.RunOnUiThread(KCRdestActivity.this, mp1, sb1);
                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Play1)).setText("❙❙");
                                selectedMP = 1;
                                delayTime = mp2.getDuration() - 130;
                                Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, delayTime + "##" + destdir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (langId > 3) {
                        return;
                    }
                    langId++;
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, delayTime);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you describe the reason why you want to do that ?

Comment: postDelayed means that the code block inside run will be triggered after delay time. This means that the delay time value was already referenced before the run function is called.

Comment: And also, the loop is executed synchronously in contrast with the postDelayed. So the loop has a high chance of completing its execution before the first run is called, meaning, the delay will always be the same.

Comment: I added an alternative approach using AsyncTask. You can check that.

Comment: @VivekMishra the goal of this: replace toast with mediaplayer code, and play 3 soundtrack with different delay, every soundtrack should play -150ms before the previous one ends. those soundtrack have been renamed with "_1" "_2" "_3" tag, that's why I use "1 2 3" for the loop

Comment: then you can do that by getting total duration and current duration of the current playing track of media player check for the difference, if less than 150ms start another track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to write that much lines of code, try this:

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
int langId = 1;
handler1.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (langId > 3) {
                       return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, String.valueOf(langId++), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 2000);  // If delay time is constant!
                }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
int langId = 1;
handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (langId > 3) {
                       return;
                    }
                    if (langId == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        delayTime = 2000;
                    }
                    if (langId == 2) {
                        Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        delayTime = 2000;
                    }
                    if (langId == 3) {
                        Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        delayTime = 2000;
                    }
                    langId++;
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, delayTyme);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use asyntask along with Thread.sleep(2000) in the doInBackground method

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your code out of run method and put into for loop directly. Put only toast inside run method.

**1.** Implement a timer task and schedule it after every 2seconds

```
int value = 1;
Timer timer = new Timer();


TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        value++;
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 2000);
```

OR

**2.** Change your code to

Try

```
for (langId = 1; langId <= 3; langId++) {
    delayTime += 2000;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, String.valueOf(langId), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }, delayTime);
}
```

Comment: Can't the handler be defined once outside the loop ?

Comment: Yes, you can define it outside as well

Comment: To note here and correct me if I am wrong, that the updated value inside the run method might not be visible to the main thread. Hence, the main thread might not see the updated value. value can be declared as volatile to ensure this visibility.

Comment: seconds method didn't work. I have to get langId inside Toast so I can do things related to the value of langId

Comment: If you declare langId as a class member/field, then there will be no error

Comment: I think, a recursive call is usually better in these cases, because UI is not blocked inside the loop when range is quite large

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  MainActivity.....
  long Delay = 2000;
  oncreate().........
  Timer  Run = new Timer();

    TimerTask Show = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do something.........
        }
    };

    Run.schedule(Show, Delay);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AsyncTask` for this.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int langId = 1; langId <= 3; langId++) {
            publishProgress(langId);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Toast.makeText(KCRdestActivity.this, String.valueOf(values[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method

declare global these classes

```
private int TIME_STAMP_INTERVAL = 2000;
private Runnable runnable = null;
private int count=0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

then add this in method which u call

```
runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(context, ""count++, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, TIME_STAMP_INTERVAL);
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score -2):

A quick and dirty way to achieve this using `Thread.sleep(2000)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable forLoop = () -> {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(i); // Do your stuff
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(forLoop).start();

}
```

**Output:**

`1 -> 2000ms -> 2 -> 2000ms -> 3`

Comment: @AliAhsan better now?

Comment: don't take it personal. I just mentioned in comments to discourage peoples to try any solution which work for them even though not recommended by docs

Comment: @AliAhsan it's ok, no hard feelings here :)